# Implement logging in library across multiple Target Framework Versions

Tags: .net, logging, .net-core, .net-5, .net-standard

I've written a library that is compiled against multiple [Target Framework Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-frameworks).  I need to log in my library, but I don't want to force the end user to a specific logging framework. e.g. I don't want to take a dependency on something like log4net internally that then causes the end user to have to upgrade their version of log4net, cause nasty assembly binding issues, or in any way impact the end user.

I'm looking for some generic solution to this problem that works all the way back to the .Net 4.5 framework through 4.8, .net core *, .net standard 2.0, .net 5 & 6.

I'm sure this problem has been encountered before but I'm having no luck finding articles about solutions people have come up with that matches my situation; specifically the TFM versions I need to support.

I'm starting to lean towards having the end user pass `Action<>` delegates into my library's initial config that represent the `Info`, `Warn`, `Error`, `Debug` methods specific to their logging setup, and just hold a reference to those, but I'm sure there are probably garbage collection issues with that. Holding out hope for another solution.

Answer (score 1):

you could use `ILogger<TCategoryName>` and `ILoggerFactory` interfaces
they are part of the [.NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#applies-to) (from .NET core 1 => .NET 6)

They are also available in the following NuGet packages:

- The interfaces are in [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions).
- The default implementations are in [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/).

so that the user has the choice to integrate any logging framework they want because all the frameworks are already supporting those interfaces, so you are safe to rely on them.

another approach is to provide your own abstraction, create an interface ILogger with all the necessary methods and provide a default implementation for it that only logs to the console, and then give the user the choice to choose from a pre-defined implementation or provide their own implementation.

but I will suggest going with the logging abstraction provided by Microsoft.